# Concealing method results

Tags: appsec, java

I have to maintain a java application with security code I am not sure is really useful and the original purpose is not clear (and the original developer is long gone).

Basically, the code will check some security parameters before allowing the user to do something. There are several methods that do several checks. The trick here is that these methods isXXXCorrect, isYYYAllowed, isZZZTampered, etc... do not return true or false.

The code has two constants TRUE and FALSE which are initialized to randomly generated strings when the program is launched. Then the methods return TRUE or FALSE, and the calling methods check for equality to TRUE or FALSE.

Some context: the app is, in the end, a standalone program installed by the end user who might want to hack the program and deactivate these securities. On packaging, the code is obfuscated with zelix klassmaster. The trick is on local methods calling other local methods, no network communication is involved.

My question is, does this trick have any real use to secure my code?

**Edit** : clarification after comments and further thoughts of my own.

I know that no security will be enough if someone really wants to reverse engeneer/modify the software. I know that, even if reasonable efforts are made to make this hard (obfuscation, etc.), no effort will ever be absolutely enough in this context. But if some of these efforts add no value and clutter the code...

I wonder what the initial developer was trying to achieve here. Improve obfuscation? We use Zelix Klassmaster and it performs encryption of the strings in code, so the "random string" aspect does not seem to me to have an added value in that regard. Prevent some attacks? This would protect from a man in the middle between a local method and another local method? Does this even make sense?

Comment: Are you asking "Does this make the code more obfuscated", or "Does this make the code more secure"?  It'll always be possible to reverse engineer/modify the code, even with the randomized constants.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Like you said in another comment, I really wonder what is the purpose of the code, what is the great, or not so great, or completely lame, idea behind this. I edited the question.

Comment: seems like they are dummy methods, but hard to say without seeing the code.  Can you include one of those methods in the post?  Do any other classes extend/override those methods?  Are there also dummy interfaces?

Comment: No, they are not dummy methods. I know they are used and I know what they do. I only don't know if it is useful that they use the aforementioned constants as return codes instead of returning true and false.

Answer (score 0):

No, all of that is pointless. An attacker could reverse engineer your program and nullify all of your security checks, even with all of the efforts you described. Any code or data that you don't want the user to have 100% full control over needs to live on a server, period.

Comment: This isn't always true.  For example, DRM protection works because it takes time and effort to crack, not because it is impossible to crack.

Comment: @NathanMerrill There's definitely a parallel between this and DRM, but I'd argue that DRM doesn't work.

Comment: I largely agree with you, but it pretty much depends on their attack vector.  I think that's the issue the OP has: They have no idea what the purpose of the old code was trying to do.